# Caesar Cipher program in C

Tags: c, beginner, caesar-cipher

I'm a beginner-intermediate C++ programmer, and I never used or understood C input & validation. I just always used C++ streams.

Anyway, I just want code critique, as I have never used the C input functions (I admit, I have used and like `printf()`!  I even made my own `sprintf()`, compatible with the C++ string class.)

I hope my code is good. I tend to get code to work properly, completely ignoring formatting and performance, then later once it works I make it look and run nicely.

**caesar.c**

```
#include <string.h> /* for strlen() */
#include "caesar.h"

char *getCipherText(char *src, int key) {
    int len = strlen(src);
    int i = 0;
    int ch = 0;

    /* Loop over each char in src */
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        ch = (int)src[i]; /* Convert the char to int to prevent many uneccecary casts */
        if (ch >= 65 && ch <= 90) { /* If the char is uppercase */
            ch += key; /* add the key */
            if (ch > 90) ch -= 26; /* if the char is higher than the highest uppercase char, sub 26 */
            if (ch < 65) ch += 26; /* if the char is lower than the lowest uppercase char, add 26 */
            src[i] = (char)ch; /* set the current char in src to the char value of ch */
        } else if (ch >= 97 && ch <= 122) { /* else if it's lowercase */
            ch += key; /* add the key */
            if (ch > 122) ch -= 26; /* if the char is higher than the highest lowercase char, sub 26 */
            if (ch < 97) ch += 26; /* if the char is lower than the lowest lowercase char, add 26 */
            src[i] = (char)ch; /* set the current char in src to the char value of ch */
        } 
        /* an else case is not needed, since we are modifying the original. */
    }
    /* Return a pointer to the char array passed to us */
    return src;
}

char *getPlainText(char *src, int key) {
    /* Since getCipherText adds the key to each char, adding a negative key 
     * is equivalent to subtracting a positive key. Easier than re-implementing.
     */
    return getCipherText(src, -key);
}
```

**caesar.h**

```
char *getCipherText(char *src, int key);
char *getPlainText(char *src, int key);
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h> /* for printf(), sscanf(), fgetc() and fgets() */
#include <stdlib.h> /* for malloc() and free() */
#include <string.h> /* for strlen() */
#include "caesar.h"

/* Size of text buffer to read into */
#define BUFS 1024

/* Size of buffer for reading misc. items, i.e. for the get_int() function */
#define TBUFS 128

/* Get char, no new lines */
int getc_nnl() {
    int ch = '\n';

    /* While ch is a newline or carriage return, read another char */
    while (ch == '\n' || ch == '\r')
        ch = fgetc(stdin);

    /* Return the char, promoted to an integer */
    return ch; 
}

/* Get an integer */
int get_int() {
    char *s = (char*)malloc(TBUFS); s[0] = '\0';
    int i = 0;
    /* Read a string, and later parse the int in case there are no ints to read */
    while (strlen(s) <= 1) 
        fgets(s, TBUFS, stdin);

    /* Parse the int. Using sscanf because scanf on stdin leaves the file caret at a unknown position. */
    sscanf(s, "%d", &i);

    /* Return the int - if sscanf found nothing, it's already 0 */
    return i;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *text = NULL;
    int key = 0;
    int ch = 0;

    while(1) {  /* Forever loop, until we break; out */

        /* Prompt for an option */
        printf("Encrypt, Decrypt, or Quit? (e/d/q) ");
        ch = getc_nnl(); 

        /* Make sure they gave us a valid option - if not, keep prompting! */
        while (ch != 'e' && ch != 'E' && ch != 'd' && ch != 'D' && ch != 'q' && ch != 'Q') {
            printf("Invalid option. Encrypt, Decrypt, or Quit? (e/d/q) ");
            ch = getc_nnl();
        }

        /* If the user wants to quit... */
        if (ch == 'q' || ch == 'Q') 
            break; /* ...then break out of the loop */

        /* Allocate buffer for text (I set text[0] to a null-terminator due to later strlen() calls) */
        text = (char*)malloc(BUFS); text[0] = '\0';

        /* Get the text to encrypt - If user entered nothing,
         * or fgets() is reading only a newline (from the fgetc calls), keep reading.
         */
        printf("Please enter your text: ");
        while (strlen(text) <= 1)
            fgets(text, BUFS, stdin);

        /* Get the integer key to encrypt/decrypt with. If it's invalid, keep prompting! :) */
        printf("Ok, now what key should I use? (1 - 25) ");
        key = get_int();
        while (key < 1 || key > 25) {
            printf("Invalid key. Please enter a number between 1 and 25: ");
            key = get_int();
        }

        /* Ok, we have our data - now, did they say encrypt or decrypt? */
        if (ch == 'e' || ch == 'E') {
            /* Encrypt, and print the result */
            getCipherText(text, key);
            printf("Ok. Here's your encrypted text: %s\n", text);
        } else if (ch == 'd' || ch == 'D') {
            /* Decrypt, and print the result */
            getPlainText(text, key);
            printf("Ok. Here's your decrypted text: %s\n", text);
        }

        /* Free our malloc, so we don't have a memory overrun */
        free(text);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
/* Loop over each char in src */
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
```

To some C programmers, writing string manipulation like this is like speaking in a foreign accent.  Consider this:

```
while (*src)
{
    // TODO: do something with *src

    src++;
}
```

Moreover, the way you've written it you're looping through all chars twice.  (`strlen` will loop through all chars to find the length, and then you'll loop through again to perform the cypher.)  The code above loops through exactly once.

```
ch = (int)src[i]; /* Convert the char to int to prevent many uneccecary casts */
```

I'm not sure what is meant by this comment, or where the confusion lies.  I'd say do it without casts if you can.  (It looks like you can.)

```
if (ch >= 65 && ch <= 90) { /* If the char is uppercase */
```

Are you hardcoding ASCII?  That's a little weird.  You can do `ch >= 'A'` etc.  Better yet, `isupper` from `ctype.h`.

```
while (strlen(s) <= 1) 
    fgets(s, TBUFS, stdin);
```

This looks very weird.  First of all `strlen(s) <= 1` should produce a result equivalent to `!s[0] || !s[1]`, except that `strlen` will traverse the entire string, which is bad.  But overall the "while length of string is <= 1" approach is a bit confusing...  I think cleaner code would call `fgets` first, then observe the result.

**Update, having glanced at the code again:** Also, your buffer sizes are small and fixed-size.  At those sizes it's probably more sensible to make them stack-allocated arrays instead of calling `malloc`.

Comment: Wow, thanks a ton. I am new to C-style programming, having used the C++ `string` class whenever I could. And I am taking your comment about making my pointers "stack-allocated arrays" to mean use `char bla[TBUFS];` rather than `char *bla = (char*)malloc(TBUFS);` ? ----- I will work on my code, as per your [really good] suggestions, and will update the code on my OP. Thanks!!!! (And especially thanks for explaining why you suggested each thing! :)   )

Comment: Updated the code on my OP - did I properly implement what you meant in the getCipherText() function?

Comment: @FurryHead Yes, the edits you have made address some of my points, particularly about `while(*src++)` and the fixed-size buffers.

Answer (score 4):

I think I'd change a few things. First of all, I would generally *avoid* making the program interactive. At least for me, a program like this that fundamentally carries out a single operation should (by strong preference) let me enter everything necessary on the command line. If you insist, you can allow interactive use as well, but *don't* force me to respond to your prompts instead of entering data as I see fit, and don't stop me from creating scripts and such to handle such things with even less work if I choose to.

Second, I think I'd segment the problem into functions slightly differently. At the bottom level, I'd have a function that just takes one input character, and returns one encoded/decoded character:

```
int cipher(int ch, int key) {   
    if (islower(ch)) return (ch-'a' + key) % 26 + 'a';
    if (isupper(ch)) return (ch-'A' + key) % 26 + 'A';
    return ch;
}
```

Then, if you really want to deal in strings, as a layer on top of that, I'd have something that knows how to deal with strings of characters:

```
void encode(char *s, int key) { 
    while (*s)
        *s = cipher(*s++, key);
}

void decode(char *s, int key) { 
    while (*s) 
        *s = cipher(*s++, -key);
}
```

Then, as the top layer enough to open files, and act as a filter:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    char buffer[256];
    // skipping error checking for now.
    int key = atoi(argv[1]);

    while (fgets(buffer, 256, stdin))
        if (tolower(argv[2][0] == 'd')
            puts(decode(buffer));
        else
            puts(encode(buffer));
    return 0;
}
```

Or, if you don't mind a tiny bit of trickiness:

```
typedef int (*func)(int);

func f = tolower(argv[2][0]) == 'd' ?
       decode : 
       encode;

while (fgets(buffer, 256, stdin))
    puts(f(buffer));
```

Alternatively, you can ignore using strings at all, and just deal in single characters throughout:

```
int encode(int ch, int key) { 
    if (islower(ch)) ch =  (ch-'a' + key) % 26 + 'a';
    else if (isupper(ch)) ch = (ch-'A' + key) % 26 + 'A';
    return ch;
}

int decode(int ch, int key) { 
    return encode(ch, -key);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    int ch;
    int key = atoi(argv[1]);

    int (*f)(int) = argv[2][0] == 'd' ?
        decode :
        encode;

    while (EOF != (ch=getchar()))
         putchar(f(ch));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I edited your encode() function, as it did not handle a negative key being passed (i.e. -2 being passed when the char is 'A') and added error checking (atoi() returns 0 if there is no valid number) ----- Thanks a ton, though!! You drastically reduced my code size, while adding more features! Woo! (EDIT: Also, I updated the code on my OP -- Thanks again!)

Comment: @FurryHead: sure -- it's always a bit tricky dealing with (what looks like) homework. I try to nudge in what I think is a reasonable direction, but still leave at least a little for you (the OP generally) to think about/deal with. It's good to see somebody really thinking and running with it.

Comment: Actually, it's not homework. Programming is just a hobby of mine, and I try to learn things thoroughly. (And I try to eliminate _every_ bug I can - I really, really, *really* hate buggy programs!) I've used several languages, just to see what they're like, but I've never used a language without objects/classes. (Until now; using C ) I can't imagine how I will manage without Objects! LOL...      Anyway, thanks again - I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @FurryHead: The fact that it's self-assigned doesn't mean it isn't homework! :-)

Comment: Bad trickiness.  Just use `if (argv[2][0] == 'd') key = 26-key;`, and lost the decode function entirely.

Answer (score 3):

- after `malloc` check result to NULL
- getCipherText check `src` to NULL, if `strlen` get NULL string it crushed.
- function `get_int` free `s` string before return result